# как дешифровать SlowAES?

Tags: php, aes

На сайте стоит защита от парсинга.
с помощью js декшифруетрся и получается кука, далее перенаправляя.
С помощью библиотеки js(https://code.google.com/archive/p/slowaes/)
получается дешифровать, но с той же библиотекой на php уже проблема.
На просторах интернета нашел кто уже сталкивался с похожим случаям, но он так и не дописал решение на php https://hms.lostcut.net/viewtopic.php?id=842